When are two object guaranteed to keep getting further and further away?
In a two-body problem, it is known (if I understand correctly) that if the specific orbital energy of the system is $\varepsilon \geq0$, then the objects must eventually escape each other. My question is, how can we test if it's going to happen "right now", meaning for given $m_1, m_2, \vec{r_1}, \vec{r_2}, \vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}$, what conditions can be met so that the two objects will not get any closer to each other, and start drifting immediately?
Perhaps if $\varepsilon \geq0$ and also $\vec{r}_{12}\cdot\vec{v}_{12}\geq0$, that'll suffice? (where those are the relative position and velocity respectively). But I'm not sure how I'd prove this.
A condition that guarantees immediate escape but isn't required for it is also fine by me, but the more precise it is, the better.

With the given parameters you can compute the energy (kinetic plus potential), try that and you will see if it is positive!

@JosBergervoet But I want to know if the distance between the objects will immediately increase. Two objects can have enough energy to escape eachother, yet still come closer at some moment.

With the given parameters you can also compute the relative velocity (you need only $\vec{v_2}-\vec{v_1}$). Then you see whether they will immediately move towards or away from each other (project on $\vec{r_2}-\vec{r_1}$). So what question do you think is unanswered?!

@JosBergervoet If the relative velocity is negative, is that a guarantee that they will never again get any closer to eachother? Not only right then, but also at any later time?

Ah, I see! Yes they can only come closer together once, not multiple times. That is because the only orbits possible when the energy is positive are parabolic and hyperbolic, in both cases they are approaching each other followed by moving away from each other, only one turning point exists.

@JosBergervoet That's great to hear. Thank you!

I think condition $\frac {v^2}{2} \geq \frac {G(m_1+m_2)}{r}$ is pretty enough.

@AgniusVasiliauskas You're saying then that the specific orbital energy is non-negative. But a two body system can have that, and yet have the two bodies come closer at some point. I want a condition for when they will never come closer again.

Maybe $\varepsilon = 0$ part is a bit undefined, because it's an edge case. But let's say body has reached greater than zero specific orbital energy. In this case potential energy is not enough to overcome body kinetic energy. So to say body has reached escape velocity. If you say that in this case body still can come closer together,- then according to you where this additional body traction comes from ? I think this scenario is impossible.

m1=0.5, m2=0.5, r1=(0,0), r2=(1,0), v1=(1, 0), v2=(0,0). Then v^2 /2 = 1/2, and G(m1+m2)/r=G*(0.5+0.5)/1=G. But G is much less than 1/2. So the condition is satisfied but they are getting closer. The problem is that their velocity is towards one another.
